# Make calls with F3507G WWAN adapter

Tags: 18.10, phone

[EDIT: So it appears that after I cancel the call I made from F3507g to other number the device is still accessible.]

I'v got my F3507g WWAN adapter recognized and SIM unlocked. I'm able to send/recieve messages and read contacts from SIM. Fine!

But when I try to make call with wammu nothing appears to happen but the phone get stuckin a busy mode... The same happens if someone try to call me.

Then I gave a try to xgnokii. I was able to send a dial. But after responding to it there is no sound in nor out. And after canceling the phone again get stuck in a busy mode.

I know there's a lack of informations yet. Please Tell me what to do to gather more of them. And maybe find a solution.

Thhank's!

```
jean@jean:~$ uname -a
Linux jean 4.18.0-15-lowlatency #16-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 7 12:28:15 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

That's what I get with gnokii --identify

```
jean@jean:~$ gnokii --identify
gnokiid Version 0.6.31
LOG: debug mask is 0x1
LOG: rlpdebug mask is 0x1
LOG: xdebug mask is 0x1
Config read from file /home/jean/.gnokiirc.
phone instance config:
model = AT
port = /dev/ttyACM0
connection = serial
initlength = default
serial_baudrate = 19200
serial_write_usleep = -1
handshake = software
require_dcd = 0
smsc_timeout = 10
rfcomm_channel = 0
sm_retry = 0
Initializing AT capable mobile phone ...
Serial device: opening device /dev/ttyACM0
Serial device: setting RTS to high and DTR to high
Message sent: 0x00 / 0x0004
41 54 5a 0d                                     | ATZ             
write: [ATZ<cr>]
read : [^A^FZ<cr><cr><lf>+CME ERROR: 262<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x00 / 0x0017
05 01 06 5a 0d 0d 0a 2b 43 4d 45 20 45 52 52 4f |    Z   +CME ERRO
52 3a 20 32 36 32 0d                            | R: 262          
Received message type 00
Message sent: 0x00 / 0x0005
41 54 45 31 0d                                  | ATE1            
write: [ATE1<cr>]
read : [ATE1<cr><cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x00 / 0x000b
02 41 54 45 31 0d 0d 0a 4f 4b 0d                |  ATE1   OK      
Received message type 00
Message sent: 0x00 / 0x000a
41 54 2b 43 4d 45 45 3d 31 0d                   | AT+CMEE=1       
write: [AT+CMEE=1<cr>]
read : [AT+CMEE=1<cr><cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x00 / 0x0010
02 41 54 2b 43 4d 45 45 3d 31 0d 0d 0a 4f 4b 0d |  AT+CMEE=1   OK 
Received message type 00
Message sent: 0x06 / 0x0007
41 54 2b 47 4d 4d 0d                            | AT+GMM          
write: [AT+GMM<cr>]
read : [AT+GMM<cr><cr><lf>F3507g<cr><lf><cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x06 / 0x0017
02 41 54 2b 47 4d 4d 0d 0d 0a 46 33 35 30 37 67 |  AT+GMM   F3507g
0d 0a 0d 0a 4f 4b 0d                            |     OK          
Received message type 06
Message sent: 0x06 / 0x0008
41 54 2b 43 47 4d 49 0d                         | AT+CGMI         
write: [AT+CGMI<cr>]
read : [AT+CGMI<cr><cr><lf>Ericsson<cr><lf><cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x06 / 0x001a
02 41 54 2b 43 47 4d 49 0d 0d 0a 45 72 69 63 73 |  AT+CGMI   Erics
73 6f 6e 0d 0a 0d 0a 4f 4b 0d                   | son    OK       
Received message type 06
Message sent: 0x63 / 0x0009
41 54 2b 43 53 43 53 3f 0d                      | AT+CSCS?        
write: [AT+CSCS?<cr>]
read : [AT+CSCS?<cr><cr><lf>+CSCS: "GSM"<cr><lf><cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x63 / 0x001f
02 41 54 2b 43 53 43 53 3f 0d 0d 0a 2b 43 53 43 |  AT+CSCS?   +CSC
53 3a 20 22 47 53 4d 22 0d 0a 0d 0a 4f 4b 0d    | S: "GSM"    OK  
Received message type 63
Initialisation completed
Message sent: 0x06 / 0x0007
41 54 2b 47 4d 4d 0d                            | AT+GMM          
write: [AT+GMM<cr>]
read : [AT+GMM<cr><cr><lf>F3507g<cr><lf><cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x06 / 0x0017
02 41 54 2b 47 4d 4d 0d 0d 0a 46 33 35 30 37 67 |  AT+GMM   F3507g
0d 0a 0d 0a 4f 4b 0d                            |     OK          
Received message type 06
Message sent: 0x06 / 0x0008
41 54 2b 43 47 4d 49 0d                         | AT+CGMI         
write: [AT+CGMI<cr>]
read : [AT+CGMI<cr><cr><lf>Ericsson<cr><lf><cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x06 / 0x001a
02 41 54 2b 43 47 4d 49 0d 0d 0a 45 72 69 63 73 |  AT+CGMI   Erics
73 6f 6e 0d 0a 0d 0a 4f 4b 0d                   | son    OK       
Received message type 06
Message sent: 0x06 / 0x0008
41 54 2b 43 47 4d 52 0d                         | AT+CGMR         
write: [AT+CGMR<cr>]
read : [AT+CGMR<cr><cr><lf>R1B/1<cr><lf><cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x06 / 0x0017
02 41 54 2b 43 47 4d 52 0d 0d 0a 52 31 42 2f 31 |  AT+CGMR   R1B/1
0d 0a 0d 0a 4f 4b 0d                            |     OK          
Received message type 06
Message sent: 0x06 / 0x0008
41 54 2b 43 47 53 4e 0d                         | AT+CGSN         
write: [AT+CGSN<cr>]
read : [AT+CGSN<cr><cr><lf>354143023514987<cr><lf><cr><lf>OK<cr><lf>]
Message received: 0x06 / 0x0021
02 41 54 2b 43 47 53 4e 0d 0d 0a 33 35 34 31 34 |  AT+CGSN   35414
33 30 32 33 35 31 34 39 38 37 0d 0a 0d 0a 4f 4b | 3023514987    OK
0d                                              |                 
Received message type 06
IMEI         : 354143023514987
Fabricant: Ericsson
Aucune section flags dans le fichier de configuration.
Modele       : F3507g
Nom du produit : F3507g
Revision     : R1B/1
Serial device: closing device
```